# How to join different tables based on different conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have tables 'TTPBH' which has column 'KEY_VALUE',
'SUB' which has column 'SERIAL' and 'SERIAL_NO'
'INVOICE' which has column 'ACCOUNT'

I want to join 'TTPBH'  with 'SUB', 'INVOICE' as:

- If length 'KEY_VALUE'  > 16, 'TTPBH' join 'SUB' on 'KEY_VALUE' = 'SERIAL_NO'
- If length 'KEY_VALUE'  = 16, 'TTPBH' join 'SUB' on 'KEY_VALUE' = 'SERIAL'
- If length 'KEY_VALUE'  < 16, 'TTPBH' join 'INVOICE' on 'KEY_VALUE' = 'ACCOUNT'

Please help me write code in SQL. Many thanks!

Comment: Please tag only a **single** RDBMS.

Comment: And please please provide sample data and desired results (as formatted text).

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags... feel free to add the correct **one** back.

Comment: Its 3 conditions with select - ```union all``` can be used here.

Comment: Please show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it. The join conditions are straightforward because you've already specified them

Comment: What database (RDBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write the conditions you listed using the valid syntax for your rdbms; for example, for SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM TTPBH TT
     
     LEFT JOIN
     SUB SB
     on ((LEN(TT.KEY_VALUE) > 16 AND TT.KEY_VALUE=SB.SERIAL_NO)
         OR
         (LEN(TT.KEY_VALUE) = 16 AND TT.KEY_VALUE=SB.SERIAL)
        )

     LEFT JOIN
     INVOICE INV
     ON LEN(TT.KEY_VALUE) < 16 AND TT.KEY_VALUE=INV.ACCOUNT
```